# MVC ModelState Validation of List of Complex Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate, complextype

So, I have a `User` Model class. It has List of `UnitViewModel`.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<UnitViewModel> DesiredUnits { get; set; }
}

public class UnitViewModel
{
    public Guid? UnitID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "NAMEEE")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create new `User` I post `UserViewModel` from my view. Here I get `ModelState.IsValid` `false`. This happens because Validation also checks the `UnitViewModel.Name` property which is null (and it is normal since I create `User` and I have `checkbox` list for `UnitViewModel`. User selects `UnitViewModel` from existing `UnitViewModel` list).

I could fix it in a horrible way of `ModelState["DesiredUnits[0].UnitID"].Errors.Clear()` by foreach loop but I won't.

So, what would be the solution? How can I disable validation of list of complex property of a model?

**UPDATE** 
Another solution, I am currently using, is to have `HiddenFor(m=>m.Name)` in `UnitViewModel`'s editor template but disadvantage with this approach is that `Name` is unnecessary when I already have label in editortemplate. Also, if I had any more required fields I would have to have corresponding hidden input for each of them.

Comment: can you render your create-view in a way that you don't have any fields that link the Property of DesiredUnits ?
Thant way the List of UnitViewModel would remain empty and no validation of Name get done

Comment: I have `EditorTemplate` for `DesiredUnits` which has `UnitID` and `Name`. And when creating `User` I have to show it since they need to choose desired units

Comment: try to use a nullable DesiredUnits  then

Comment: Type of `DesiredUnits` is List so, it is nullable itself

Answer (score 0):

If your request view model contains properties or validation rules that aren't required for the specified view you should create a new object for this purpose.

```
// New model, specific for request
public class UserRequestViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(UserRequestViewModel requestModel)
{
    //... do something

    // Get the values required to return to the view
    var responseModel = new UserViewModel();
    responseModel.DesiredUnits = new List<UnitViewModel>();

    // Return the response model
    return View(responseModel);
}
```

If you do it this way, it is clear to anyone developing for your application, what is acceptable to be posted to your action.

Alternatively, if you decide that you can't bare to create a **whole** new model for this purpose, move your validation into the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel requestResponseModel)
{
    // Perform validation
    for (var i = 0; i < requestResponseModel.DesiredUnits.Count(); i++)
    {
        var validationErrorKey = string.Format("DesiredUnits[{0}]", i);

        // Is the Name property empty?
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestResponseModel.DesiredUnits[i].Name))
        {


            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Posted Name cannot be empty", validationErrorKey );
        }
    }

    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // There was a model validation error
    }

    //... do something

    // Return the response model
    return View(requestResponseModel);
}
```

As a last resort, you could use, but I'm not sure if this prevents the validation of the field - you'd need to give that a go:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude = "DesiredUnits")]UserViewModel requestResponseModel)
{
    // ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   [HttpPost]       
    public ActionResult CreateEnquiryOnly([Bind(Include="FirstName,LastName")]UserViewModel userviewmodel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {       
        }
    }
```